# Using blockcypher BitcoinJs at clientside is secure or not?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoinjs, node.js, signrawtransaction

I am trying to create new transaction using bitcoinjs at client side.
Is it a secure way to create a transaction from Client side, which includes curl call.

Scenario, if I start from creating the new address using the library it includes curl call which can be easily accessible from the browsers dev tool which leads to direct access to my private keys.

So, is it safe to handle the transaction at client side or not?